# Am I bearing jariyah sin from doing that I don’t know it have evil

Tags: fiqh, sin

Is it a sin for doing something we didn’t know was a sin?
Here’s the situation of the example :
My teacher said she wants us doing a task and study from a certain website. When she said she gave us the link,  it turned out to be the wrong link. I then proceeded to ask for the correct link and ask to post it on groupclass in which she agreed and did so. When I clicked the link, I realized the link contained many haram elements such as philosophy, music, girls not covering their awrah nor wearing hijab, etc.

Note:

- The website is like Google Classroom
- I study in a mix school
- I study in a school that various in religious diversity
- My parents don’t allow me to switch schools

Comment: "The reward of deeds depends upon the intentions and every person will get the reward according to what he has intended."

Comment: What is jariyah sin?

Answer (score 1):

in islam intention is very important. you are in a very difficult situation, and so allah understands that you are not intending to haram. there is no sin on you, i suggest that you could try to do your work while using the website but try your best not to look at or listen to any of the haram on that site.

Answer (score 0):

Prophet Muhammad (SAWW) once said,

> **"The reward of deeds depends upon the intention and every person will get the reward according to what he has intended."** (Sahih
> Bukhari, Kitab-ul-Imaan, Hadith No. 53)

This hadith itself clears many misconceptions that we mostly have.